# trim junk characters from variable

Tags: unix, shell

I have a variable in my shell script that works as per my expectations.
But when I use that variable as filename, I get ?? at the beginning of the string. How do I trim the junk characters?

I use $(some command) to create this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways to fix your variable but first we need to know what to get rid of (i.e., the output of `someCommand`).

If, for example, it's always putting two characters at the front that you don't need, you could use:

```
x=$(someCommand | cut -c3-)
```

If you want to strip off all characters in the output outside the range 0x20 through 0x7e (the non-printable characters from `ASCII`), you could use:

```
x=$(someCommand | tr -d '[\000-\037\177]')
```

Ideally, you would run `someCommand | od -xcb` to get an actual hex dump of what it's outputting. Then we can help you out further.

*Update:*

Based on your new data (that the output is `\n\nSomeName27-Oct-2009-14-33.sql.zip`), you should be able to use `sed '/^$/d'` to strip out the empty lines.

```
pax> echo '

SomeName27-Oct-2009-14-33.sql.zip' | od -xcb

0000000 0a0a 6f53 656d 614e 656d 3732 4f2d 7463
         \n  \n   S   o   m   e   N   a   m   e   2   7   -   O   c   t
        012 012 123 157 155 145 116 141 155 145 062 067 055 117 143 164
0000020 322d 3030 2d39 3431 332d 2e33 7173 2e6c
          -   2   0   0   9   -   1   4   -   3   3   .   s   q   l   .
        055 062 060 060 071 055 061 064 055 063 063 056 163 161 154 056
0000040 697a 0a70
          z   i   p  \n
        172 151 160 012
0000044

pax> echo '

SomeName27-Oct-2009-14-33.sql.zip' | sed '/^$/d' | od -xcb

0000000 6f53 656d 614e 656d 3732 4f2d 7463 322d
          S   o   m   e   N   a   m   e   2   7   -   O   c   t   -   2
        123 157 155 145 116 141 155 145 062 067 055 117 143 164 055 062
0000020 3030 2d39 3431 332d 2e33 7173 2e6c 697a
          0   0   9   -   1   4   -   3   3   .   s   q   l   .   z   i
        060 060 071 055 061 064 055 063 063 056 163 161 154 056 172 151
0000040 0a70
          p  \n
        160 012
0000042
```

That's assuming those `\n` markers are actually *two* newlines (`{'\n','\n'}`). If (for some bizarre reason) they're the *four* characters `{'\\','n','\\','n'}`, use `cut -c5-` instead.

Comment: \n\nSomeName27-Oct-2009-14-33.sql.zip 

## I want to remove the first 2 new line characters.

Comment: sed '/^$/d'  ## thanks for this. I have one more question. How do I also remove space between two words? Some Name27-Oct-2009-14-33.sql.zip

Comment: Use "sed 's/ //g'" to remove all spaces (that's a space between those first two "/" characters in case it's not immediately obvious). You can combine that with your other sed as follows: "sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/ //g'".

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I would suggest is to use a tr command with -d option to delete the ?

---

filename=`$filename | tr -d '?'`

Answer (score 0):

filename=`echo $filename | sed 's/\?//g`